# How to get the value of Enum in HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor method?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I write an Enum for months of year that my enum use resource type for multi language.

```
public enum MonthType : byte
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "FirstMonth")]
    FirstMonth = 1,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "SecoundMonth")]
    SecoundMonth = 2,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "ThirdMonth")]
    ThirdMonth = 3,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "ForthMonth")]
    ForthMonth = 4,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "FifthMonth")]
    FifthMonth = 5,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "SixthMonth")]
    SixthMonth = 6,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "SeventhMonth")]
    SeventhMonth = 7,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "EighthMonth")]
    EighthMonth = 8,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "NinthMonth")]
    NinthMonth = 9,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "TenthMonth")]
    TenthMonth = 10,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "EleventhMonth")]
    EleventhMonth = 11,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Global.Caption), Name = "TwelfthMonth")]
    TwelfthMonth = 12
}
```

and I use it in my `HtmlHelper.DropDownlistFor`:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearOfBirth, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MonthOfBirth, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Shared.Entities.SMP.Enum.MonthType)))           )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

at run time I see just Enum's List with Resource Type.

Comment: What error its giving

Comment: I don't have any run time errors but  don't work  correct . i want read value from Resource Type. for multi language.in run time i have FirstMonth ,SecoundMonth ,ThirdMonth, .....

Comment: i want to show  "فروردین " for persian language or "January " for English language or "janvier" for french....

Comment: Depending on the chosen language's site